# How to refresh logon screensaver parameter changes?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-services, screensaver, windows-screensaver

I have a Windows service that may change the timeout on the logon screensaver in Windows (as [described here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314493).) To do that I change the following registry key to the timeout in seconds:

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop\ScreenSaveTimeOut
```

The issue is that how do I make OS "read" or *refresh* the actual screensaver timeout after a change in the registry key above?

My practice shows that it is refreshed (for sure) only when I reboot the system, but in my case I need it to be applied without the reboot.

**EDIT_1:** After suggestion below I tried, as it seems to me, all possible combinations of the flags for the following:

```
DWORD bsmInfo1 = BSM_ALLDESKTOPS;
DWORD dwFlgs = BSF_FORCEIFHUNG | BSF_IGNORECURRENTTASK | BSF_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG | BSF_SENDNOTIFYMESSAGE;
int nbsm1 = ::BroadcastSystemMessage(dwFlgs, &bsmInfo1, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)L"Windows");
DWORD bsmInfo2 = BSM_ALLDESKTOPS;
int nbsm2 = ::BroadcastSystemMessage(dwFlgs, &bsmInfo2, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)L"WindowsThemeElement");
```

to no avail :( I receive 1 as a result from both calls but it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to [resolve this](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?542917-RESOLVED-How-to-refresh-logon-screensaver-parameter-changes&p=2144895#post2144895).-.-.

Answer (score 0):

If your service is running in the same session as the logon screensaver then you can call [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `SPI_SETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT` flag.

`SystemParametersInfo` broadcasts the [`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to all top level windows to indicate that a parameter has changed.  If your code isn't running in the correct session then you could use [`BroadcastSystemMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `BSM_ALLDESKTOPS` flag to deliver the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message.  However, this does require the `SE_TCB_NAME` privilege, so your code would have to be running as SYSTEM.

I haven't actually tried this cross-session, so I can't guarantee that it works.

Comment: I tried your suggestion... please check my adjusted question. Do you have an idea which flags to call it with?

Comment: Is your code running as SYSTEM?  If not, the function succeeds but the `bsmInfo1` variable, which the function updates to indicate who got the message, doesn't contain the `BSM_ALLDESKTOPS` flag.  What value do you get in `bsmInfo1`?

Comment: And the wParam and lParam should be `SPI_SETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT` and "" respectively, i.e. `int nbsm = ::BroadcastSystemMessage(dwFlgs, &bsmInfo, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, SPI_SETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT, (LPARAM)L"");`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Yes, the code is running from a LocalSystem service. And after BroadcastSystemMessage returns 1, which I believe is success, `bsmInfo1` is set `0x1F`. Still even with your modifications the logon screensaver timeout doesn't change.

Comment: It seems like you'll need some code running in the correct session.  Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway. Btw, I did resolve it! It's not an easy solution but it works. Check the answer below.