# What is UpdatePerUserSystemParameters?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In my service I need to issue a "refresh" after changing the logon screensaver timeout. While doing research, I kept [finding references](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c5979d78-9732-41a7-8f7b-a9991e318b76/user32dllupdateperusersystemparameters-no-longer-works-windows-7-ultimate-x64?forum=w7itproui) to `UpdatePerUserSystemParameters` API. This API seems to be present in `user32.dll` but I can't find out what exact does it do? (Well, besides literally reading its name.) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was/is(?) a way for forcing the OS to refresh certain system settings by re-reading the relevant registry keys. In particular for colour schemes or desktop backgrounds. So it meant that you could change e.g. the Windows desktop wallpaper by merging a .reg file into the registry and then executing `UpdatePerUserSystemParameters` from user32.dll to make it read and apply the changed entries.

As the post you linked dictates, the [`SystemParametersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947%28VS.85%29.aspx) function is the correct way to change system parameters, and this must be done programatically rather than via a registry hack and a forced refresh from a .bat file.

Comment: Unfortunately calling `SystemParametersInfo` from a system service for my needs results in the error 1459, or ERROR_REQUIRES_INTERACTIVE_WINDOWSTATION, so it doesn't do me a thing. (I need to use it to change the logon screensaver.) On the side note, by any chance you don't know what parameters was `UpdatePerUserSystemParameters` supposed to be called with?

Comment: @c00000fd Ok, I skipped the bit about a service, sorry - just answered what was asked. I guess you are using `SPIF_SENDCHANGE` then? If so, do you get the same error if you just supply zero for that parameter? I guess you tried "Allow service to interact with desktop" option?

Comment: Yeah, I tried all the possible flags -- still the same error. Also when I make my service to "Allow service to interact with desktop" the `SystemParametersInfo` API succeeds but it makes no change to the actual logon screensaver parameters. It must be running in a different desktop in that case...

Comment: @c00000fd Yes I guess it's the session isolation that's the problem. [This post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/4088f4ed-7a7a-422d-ba83-1381a1542514/systemparametersinfo-do-not-work-on-windows7-when-the-app-is-a-service?forum=windowssecurity) and [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/31bfa13d-982b-4b1a-bff3-2761ade5214f/calling-createprocessasuser-from-service?forum=windowssecurity) may have some useful info but they were Vista and I have a vague memory that session isolation was tightened in Win7 upwards.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't call `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId` and later `WTSQueryUserToken` to obtain the logged on user token, since, well... I don't have any.

Comment: Just tried it. `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId` returned a valid session ID, but then `WTSQueryUserToken` failed with the error code `ERROR_NO_TOKEN`.

Comment: @c00000fd I see. I think I can feel another question coming on .... why not close this one down and ask about using `SystemParametersInfo` via a service instead?

Comment: Just a quick update. I was able to resolve it. Check the other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21085199/843732 and thanks for your help!