# How to change screen saver timeout and screensaverissecure in windows using c#

Tags: c#, system, screensaver

How to change screen saver timeout and screensaverissecure using user32.dll for the current user (or) any other users in windows through C# code, as my application is running with SYSTEM privileges in the background process.

When we change the value of this registry using c# or scripting HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ScreensaverTimeout
and HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ScreenSaverIsSecure
this effect is showing only after reboot of machine.

when we change the registry value using c# code with SYSTEM privileges those changes are not effecting with new values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1: ...this effect is showing only after reboot of machine:**

After updating registry, you can call [UpdatePerUserSystemParameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21085725/815938) to force Windows to reread the configuration from the registry (so the update takes effect immediately).

```
rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

**Q2: ...with SYSTEM privileges those changes are not effecting with new values:**

You need to launch a new process which is running in the same session as the current log on user, and update the registry values from the new process. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278373/how-to-start-a-process-from-windows-service-into-currently-logged-in-users-sess) is good question to get started.

Answer (score 1):

After you change windows settings like this you need to call the WinApi SendNotifyMessage with a WM_SETTINGCHANGE message to all windows. This is why your settings are not being updated until reboot. (I think you would find a logoff-on would achieve the same for that user).

WinApi
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

C# wrapper over send message
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendnotifymessage