# Windows Screen Saver not starting after settings change through Win32 APIs

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, screensaver

I'm developing a Screen Saver for a client which can be controlled remotely (don't ask!). They can change media types (namely videos and pictures), toggle the screen saver on and off, set its timeout, etc.

All of the above work except the timeout. The timeout works only when I restart the machine. Sometimes it works if I toggle between `3D Text` screensaver, then back to my screen saver.

As of the `.scr` installation of this Screen Saver, I tried both possible ways: through registry and through `InstallScreensaver` facility inside `user32.dll`. I sticked to the first approach, as it is much easier.

As of the timeouts, I also tried a variety of things:

1. Updating `ScreenSaveTimeout` directly in the registry, then calling `SystemParametersInfo` with only `SPIF_SENDCHANGE`
2. Calling `SystemParametersInfo` on `SPI_SETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT` with all combinations of `SPIF_SENDCHANGE`, `SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE` and even `SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE`

Either way I do it, the value gets updated in the Registry and when I open the `Screen Saver Settings`, the values are applied there, BUT!

But no matter what I do, it does not work after an immediate timeout change as I described above.

I even went far by calling:

```
rundll32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

^ Both in my installation facilities, manually; and I can't remember what else I tried.

The background of the project is C# .NET Core 3.1 (another don't ask!), I use only two external dependencies, one of them is LibVLC for media playback, and the resource and memory consumption is very low.

What am I missing here?

PS Heck, I even changed file ownership to the `SYSTEM` account to see if that makes a difference, but to no avail.

Comment: Did you try to read accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252082/how-to-change-screen-saver-timeout-and-screensaverissecure-in-windows-using-c-sh?rq=2)?

Comment: Didn't stumbled upon that SO question, yet. But, it's not something that I haven't tried. As the last paragraph of my question, last thing I tried running everything as `SYSTEM`; and even that didn't produce any change. Isn't there a way just to mimic what "Apply" button does on the "Screen Saver Settings" Window, lol?

Comment: have you tried calling `SHChangeNotify` after making changes in registry ? It should notify, and cause system to realod registry keys.

Comment: Google "c# winapi reset idle timer" to get ahead.